# Profiler для node.js v10

Tags: node.js, утечка-памяти, profile

Друзья, по-немногу утекает память в приложении. Нужен профайлер, способный делать слепки кучи и сравнить их (показать, что добавилось). Или хотя бы просто сделать слепки.

Comment: Используй хром.

Comment: Как раз всё что нужно тебе в Хроме, для этого пропиши в адресную строку Хрома: [chrome://inspect/#devices]
Как только запустишь node в режиме --inspect, запуск отладки будет доступен там спустя 1-2 сек.